# HTML parsing with beautifulsoup works on most URL except the one I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the links given by a search engine for academic literature from the following URL: 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date&years=2018

I am using beautifulsoup bs4 with python 3 and the code works for several test URL like wikipedia, but when I try it on the above URL, I only get 15 results from the page headers and footers, instead of >100 including the actual results from the search engine.

Here is an example of the HTML that I am trying to extract:

```
<a href="/science/article/pii/S0360319918337960" 
class="result-list-title-link u-font-serif text-s" data-rank="1" 
data-docsubtype="fla" data-hack="#"><em>Hydrogen</em> integration in power-to-gas networks</a>
```

and here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date&years=2018"
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
count = 0

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    count += 1
    print(link.get('href'))

print(count)
```

Any ideas why? I am starting to wonder if the website can be protected fom parsers.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used requests, but by including the user-agent, you should get the 100+ links.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date&years=2018"
html = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all('a')

count = 0

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    count += 1
    print(link.get('href'))

print(count)
```

**Output:**

```
#main_content
/
/browse/journals-and-books
/user/register?returnURL=%2Fsearch%3Fqs%3Dhydrogen%26show%3D25%26sortBy%3Ddate%26years%3D2018
/user/login?returnURL=%2Fsearch%3Fqs%3Dhydrogen%26show%3D25%26sortBy%3Ddate%26years%3D2018
https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15904/supporthub/sciencedirect/
/browse/journals-and-books
/user/register?returnURL=%2Fsearch%3Fqs%3Dhydrogen%26show%3D25%26sortBy%3Ddate%26years%3D2018
/user/login?returnURL=%2Fsearch%3Fqs%3Dhydrogen%26show%3D25%26sortBy%3Ddate%26years%3D2018
https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15904/supporthub/sciencedirect/
/search/advanced
/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date
/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date
/?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=relevance&years=2018
/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=relevance&years=2018
/science/article/pii/S0009250918305815
/science/journal/00092509
/science/article/pii/S0009250918305815
/science/article/pii/S0169433218321731
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218321731
https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27714/supporthub/sciencedirect/kw/register/
/science/article/pii/S0009250918303099
/science/journal/00092509
/science/article/pii/S0009250918303099
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322670
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322670
/science/article/pii/S0169433218321251
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218321251
/science/article/pii/S1878535218302673
/science/journal/18785352
/science/article/pii/S1878535218302673/pdfft?md5=82c344dc5e6a16651e226289299ccd96&pid=1-s2.0-S1878535218302673-main.pdf
/science/article/pii/S0003267018309784
/science/journal/00032670
/science/article/pii/S0003267018309784/pdfft?md5=e84a9680b080d3521ae51a10a70e9b74&pid=1-s2.0-S0003267018309784-main.pdf
/science/article/pii/S0009250918306183
/science/journal/00092509
/science/article/pii/S0009250918306183
/science/article/pii/S0378775318311868
/science/journal/03787753
/science/article/pii/S0378775318311868
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322773
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322773
/science/article/pii/S0009250918305451
/science/journal/00092509
/science/article/pii/S0009250918305451
/science/article/pii/S0958694618302759
/science/journal/09586946
/science/article/pii/S0958694618302759
/science/article/pii/S0944711318306378
/science/journal/09447113
/science/article/pii/S0944711318306378
/science/article/pii/S0360319918338710
/science/journal/03603199
/science/article/pii/S0360319918338710
/science/article/pii/S109727651830981X
/science/journal/10972765
/science/article/pii/S109727651830981X
/science/article/pii/S0169433218323298
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218323298
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322232
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322232
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322025
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322025
/science/article/pii/S0169433218335943
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218335943
/science/article/pii/S1226086X18307378
/science/journal/1226086X
/science/article/pii/S1226086X18307378
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322372
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322372
/science/article/pii/S0009250918305980
/science/journal/00092509
/science/article/pii/S0009250918305980
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322955
/science/journal/01694332
/science/article/pii/S0169433218322955
/science/article/pii/S092058611831527X
/science/journal/09205861
/science/article/pii/S092058611831527X/pdfft?md5=f7c6523835be4ded224fbc28036d7218&pid=1-s2.0-S092058611831527X-main.pdf
/science/article/pii/S1878535218302661
/science/journal/18785352
/science/article/pii/S1878535218302661/pdfft?md5=2aa04be5459c3d92b5b8e7475b075146&pid=1-s2.0-S1878535218302661-main.pdf
/search?qs=hydrogen&show=50&sortBy=date&years=2018
/search?qs=hydrogen&show=100&sortBy=date&years=2018
/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date&years=2018&offset=25
#
https://www.elsevier.com/
https://www.elsevier.com/solutions/sciencedirect
/customer/authenticate/manra
/science?_ob=ShoppingCartURL&_method=display&md5=3ff44acb300f01481824c54a2973d019
https://service.elsevier.com/app/contact/supporthub/sciencedirect/
https://www.elsevier.com/legal/elsevier-website-terms-and-conditions
https://www.elsevier.com/legal/privacy-policy
https://www.sciencedirect.com/legal/use-of-cookies
https://www.relx.com/
104
```

And if you still wanted to use urllib, just make the small modification:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date&years=2018"
req = Request(url, headers=headers)


html = urlopen(req, context=ctx).read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
count = 0

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    count += 1
    print(link.get('href'))

print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked for me with your 2nd piece of code: 
req = Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urlopen(req, context=ctx).read().decode('utf-8')
With the 1st piece of code (html = requests.get(url, headers = headers)) I get a Traceback error saying that the name 'requests' is not defined.
I need to read more about Requests and user-agent. Thanks again!

Comment: The first one is a different requests package. Did you do import requests? So you would might need to do a pip install. But the second is essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since @chitown88 has recommended including the `User-Agent`, I wanted to add on top of that you may use what seems like an `internal API` which is:
`https://www.sciencedirect.com/search/api?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date&years=2018&navigation=true`

That'd be much faster, (of course if your goal is to have the articles' `URL`s), and then you can probably do something like

```
...
r = requests.get('https://www.sciencedirect.com/search/api?qs=hydrogen&show=25&sortBy=date&years=2018&navigation=true')
data = r.json()
for result in data['searchResults']:
    print(result['pdf']['getAccessLink']
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you! How did you find out that there was an API for this website? Did you know the website or is there some way to see that? I'll read about this API and test it :-)

Comment: in Chrome, open the `Chrome DevTools`, and from within the `DevTools` click the `Network` tab, then click the `XHR` sub-button and initiate an `Ajax` call from within the website, in this case, just load more results per page.